# C#-style nameof operator in D?

Tags: d

There is a "nameof" operator in C# 6 ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn986596.aspx ). Does D have an analogue? Or some construct to emulate it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe [`stringof`](http://dlang.org/property.html#stringof) functions much in the same way. For example, a D analog to the first C# example at that link is:

```
void f(string s) {
  if (s == null) throw new Exception(s.stringof ~ " is null!");
}
```

There is also [`std.traits.fullyQualifiedName`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_traits.html#fullyQualifiedName). It does what it says on the can:

```
module mymodule;

import std.traits : fullyQualifiedName;

class MyClass { int myvar; }

pragma(msg, MyClass.myvar.stringof); // myvar
pragma(msg, fullyQualifiedName!(MyClass.myvar)); // mymodule.MyClass.myvar
```

As the first link points out, `fullyQualifiedName` may be more appropriate for compile-time code generation, where it helps to be as specific as possible to avoid clashing with local symbols.